# NoClassDefFoundError: jnlp.sample.servlet.ResourceCatalog$PathEntries

Tags: java, tomcat, jnlp, java-web-start

From time to time we have following exceptions in our application when user tries to download application via java web start:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnlp.sample.servlet.ResourceCatalog$PathEntries
    at jnlp.sample.servlet.ResourceCatalog.lookupResource(ResourceCatalog.java:109)
    at jnlp.sample.servlet.JnlpDownloadServlet.handleVersionRequest(JnlpDownloadServlet.java:233)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnlp.sample.servlet.ResourceCatalog$PathEntries
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1340)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1189)
    ... 44 more
```

or

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnlp.sample.util.VersionID
    at jnlp.sample.util.VersionString.<init>(VersionString.java:58)
```

or

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jnlp.sample.servlet.XMLNode
    at jnlp.sample.servlet.XMLParsing.convert(XMLParsing.java:67)
```

Restart of Tomcat fixes these problems.
Does anyone have any idea - what  could be the root cause of these exceptions?

**UPDATE:**
It seems to me that this exception exists on clients that run Tomcat on Java 1.5 only.
And as far as I can see there is no such exception on clients that use Java 1.4.

Comment: Have you exoerimented with adding jars directiy to tomcat?

Comment: Directly to Tomcat? No. It is production environment. And I cannot do it on production environment. And we do not have this problem on test environment.

Comment: And we have this problem only on 2 production environments. Not on all.

Answer (score 0):

It may come from automatic application reload or JSP recompilation in Tomcat.

I recommend you disable that development features thanks to [Context option](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes) `reloadable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in Tomcat 5.0.28.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31903
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33743
Fixed in 5.5.10.